# Running docker inside Kubernetes with containerd

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containerd

Since K8S v1.11 Runtime was changed from dockerd to containerd.
I'm using Jenkins over kubernetes to build docker images using Docker outside of Docker (dood).

When I tried to switch to use the socket file from conatinerd (containerd/containerd.sock was mapped ad /var/run/docker.sock) with the regular docker client a got the following error `Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/json: net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: malformed HTTP response "\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00".`

Can docker client be used with containerd?

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: as of this writing containerd didn't replace Docker, you can [install containerd](https://github.com/containerd/cri/blob/master/docs/installation.md) separately from Docker, and you can point the [Kubernetes CRI](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/) to directly talk to the containerd socket.

So, when you install Docker it does install together with containerd and the *Docker daemon* talks to it. You'll see a process like this:

```
docker-containerd --config /var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.toml
```

However, the Docker client still talks to the Docker daemon, that's why when you run the Docker client in your container you still need to talk directly to the Docker daemon (`/var/run/docker.sock`), so you can switch back to `/var/run/docker.sock` and I believe it should work.

Comment: Thanks, We are using K8S as a service in IBM. Can I point the docker daemon to talk with containerd?

Answer (score 0):

At least with [MicroK8s](https://microk8s.io/docs) 1.18 on Ubuntu 20.04, I found that a fix for this was to explicitly install Docker alongside Kubernetes.

Similar steps should apply to other Kubernetes distributions that don't include Docker.

After installing `microk8s`, you can do the following to install Docker:

```
# Shut down microk8s
sudo snap disable microk8s

# Assuming no Docker installed yet - this fixes the case  
# where Kubernetes results in this path being a directory 
rm -rf /var/run/docker.sock

sudo apt-get install docker.io

ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
# Output should show socket not directory:
#    srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Aug  6 11:50 /var/run/docker.sock

# (See https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/ for usermod + newgrp commands at this point) 

# Restart microk8s 
sudo snap enable microk8s
```

Other Kubernetes distributions may have a different way to shut down processes more selectively.

`journalctl -xe`  is useful to see any errors from Docker or Kubernetes here.

In Kubernetes manifests, be sure to use `/var/run/docker.sock` as the host path when mounting docker.sock.

Related issues:

- [hosting docker daemon alongside microk8s](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/287)
- [cannot create socket because it's a directory](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30348)

[Post-install steps for Docker on Linux](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)